# The file you are downloading cannot be opened

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an asp.net application to generate a report and open it in MS Word. That was working fine in Windows Server 2003. But after applying patches to Windows, when I try to download that MS Word file from my web application, I am getting a message

> The file you are downloading cannot be opened by the default program. It is either corrupted or it has an incorrect file type. As a security precaution, it is recommended that you cancel the download

The same application is working fine in Windows 7. Any suggestions how I can resolve this warning?

Comment: Look at the response (use browser dev tools or http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and see what's coming across the wire. You may be getting a 404 page or something else rather than the doc file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Pleas try to write whole sentences that makes your questions easier to read. See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: [E5-8 don't like no-cache and no-store](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308) values for the Cache-control header when downloading PDFs or Office documents over SSL.  If this is what you're running into, set the cacheability value to be Private for the request.